# Building a multi-record flat file

Tags: linq, file, sortedlist, flat

I'm struggling to find a proper solution for generating a flat file.

Here are some criteria I need to take care of:
The file has a header with summary of its following records
there could be multiple Collection Header Records with multiple Batch Header Records which contain multiple records of different types.

All records within a Batch have a checksum which has to be added to a batch checksum. This one has to be added to the collection Header checksum and that again to the file checksum. Also each entry in the file has a counter value.

So my plan was to create a class for each record. but what now? I have the records and the "summary records", the next step would be to bring them all in order, count the sums and then set the counters.

How should I proceed from here, should I put everything in a big SortedList? If so, how do I know where to add the latest record (It has to be added to its representing batch summary)?

My first idea was to do something like this:

```
SortedList<HeaderSummary, SortedList<BatchSummary, SortedList<string, object>>>();
```

But it is hard to navigate through the `HeaderSummaries` and `BatchSummaries` to add a object in the inner Sorted list, bearing in mind that I may have to create and add a `HeaderSummary / BachtSummary`.

Having several different ArrayLists like one for Header, one for Batch and one for the rest gives me problems when combining them to a flat file because of the order and the - yet to set - counters, while keeping the order etc.

Do you have any clever solution for such a flat file?

Comment: I don't think you want a `SortedList` - a regular `List` preserves order. Since you have basically a tree structure, I think you need to invert your thinking to have the `List`s included in the classes.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using classes to represent levels of your tree structure.

```
interface iBatch {
    public int checksum { get; set; }
}

class BatchSummary {
    int batchChecksum;
    List<iBatch> records;

    public void WriteBatch() {
        WriteBatchHeader();
        foreach (var record in records)
            batch.WriteRecord();
    }

    public void Add(iBatch rec) {
        records.Add(rec); // or however you find the appropriate batch
    }
}

class CollectionSummary {
    int collectionChecksum;
    List<BatchSummary> batches;

    public void WriteCollection() {
        WriteCollectionHeader();
        foreach (var batch in batches)
            batch.WriteBatch();
    }

    public void Add(int WhichBatch, iBatch rec) {
        batches[whichBatch].Add(rec); // or however you find the appropriate batch
    }
}

class FileSummary {
    // ... file summary info
    int fileChecksum;
    List<CollectionSummary> collections;

    public void WriteFile() {
        WriteFileHeader();
        foreach (var collection in collections)
            collection.WriteCollection();
    }

    public void Add(int whichCollection, int WhichBatch, iBatch rec) {
        collections[whichCollection].Add(whichBatch, rec); // or however you find the appropriate collection
    }
}
```

Of course, you could use a common Summary class to be more DRY, if not necessarily more clear.